# Deploying WCF Library

Tags: wcf, rest, host

I am sorry in advance for the question because it should be so easy for someone who has web programming experience, but for me ...

I have created a WCF library which gets an email address, subject and body and sends email using a gmail account. I do not know how I can deploy it.

I already published it on my host using visual studio but don't know what URL should I use to call it. Can I use it directly or I have to create a WCFapplication and add the service to it then publish the WCF app?

Also, I noticed the base address in its config file is sth like: `localhost/emailservice/service1` and I am not sure if I should edit it or not and how.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your service a RESTful service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you created a WCF library, I am assuming that you are open to host it as an IIS application or as a windows service.

Assuming that you wish to host your library as an IIS application, follow the steps mentioned in [this blog](http://www.kebabshopblues.co.uk/2013/09/20/hosting-a-wcf-service-library-project-in-iis-8-0-windows-8-0-net-4-5/) to host your WCF service library.

Please note: If you intended to host your service as an IIS application, it would have been far easier for you to create a WCF service application project in Visual Studio instead of a WCF service library project.